# What does varying the imaginary part of a complex base do graphically?

Tags: complex-numbers

I am trying to build up a visual understanding of how to calculate a complex number to the power of a complex number $(a+bi)^{c+di}$ on the complex plane.

I have figured out what variables a,c and d do, but not b.

By letting a=2 and letting c=0 we have a decaying exponential spiral $2^{di}$ where d is varied from 0 to 2$pi$. What happens to this spiral if we include various values for b? As in $(2+bi)^{di}$